# How to access phpmyadmin within fortrabbit

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, fortrabbit

I have placed the phpmyadmin directory (unpacked, as "pma") in the htdocs directory of my app on fortrabbit.

However when I visit my-app-here/pma I am given an http exception. How do I bypass the need for a defined route in routes.php?

Or, conversely, how do I create a route to access this directory's contents?

Comment: I am in no way an expert in htaccess, but look at passing pma directly to phpmyadmin, instead of passing it before. What I mean is, having a rule like RewriteRule /pma pma/index.php or something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you changed your doc root from htdocs to something else (routes.php sounds like laravel > htdocs/public).

If that's the case, simply add a new (sub)domain and point it to the htdocs/pma folder.